# delete node in BST python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.count = 1

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def _insert(self,val,node):
        if val<node.data:
            if node.left:
                self._insert(val,node.left)
            else:
                self.size+=1
                node.left = Node(val)
        elif val>node.data:
            if node.right:
                self._insert(val,node.right)
            else:
                self.size+=1
                node.right = Node(val)
        else:
            self.size+=1
            node.count+=1

    def insert(self,val):
        if not self.root:
            self.size+=1
            self.root = Node(val)
        else:
            self._insert(val,self.root)

    def _inorder(self,node):
        if node:
            self._inorder(node.left)
            self.bstview.append(node.data)
            self._inorder(node.right)

    def view(self):
        if self.root:
            self.bstview = []
            self._inorder(self.root)
            return self.bstview

    def _min(self,node):
        if node.left:
            return self._min(node.left)
        return node

    def _max(self,node):
        if node.right:
            return self._max(node.right)
        return node

    def min(self):
        if self.root:
            return self._min(self.root).data

    def max(self):
        if self.root:
            return self._max(self.root).data

    def _remove(self,val,node):
        if not node:
            return
        if val < node.data:
            node.left = self._remove(val,node.left)
        elif val > node.data:
            node.right = self._remove(val,node.right)
        else:
            if node.count >1:
                self.size-=1
                node.count-=1
                return node
            elif not node.left:
                temp = node.right
                del node
                self.size-=1
                return temp
            elif not node.right:
                temp = node.left
                del node
                self.size-=1
                return temp
            else:
                temp = self._min(node.right)
                node.data = temp.data
                node.right = self._remove(temp.data,node.right)
        return node #WHY THIS IS NECESSARY PLEASE EXPLAIN!!

    def remove(self,val):
        if self.root:
            self._remove(val,self.root)

b = BST()
for x in list(map(int,"20 10 30 5 15 25 35 3 7 23 27 40 4 45".split(" "))):
    b.insert(x)
print(b.view())
print(b.min(),b.max(),b.size)
b.remove(20)
b.remove(45)
b.remove(1)
print(b.view())
print(b.min(),b.max(),b.size)
```

In the above code of BST, why is it necessary to return `node` in the `_remove()` method? The if/elif statements are already returning nodes?

Also, I would be greatly thankful to you if you can guide me to an easy/less time consuming way to understand recursive functions (I know what they are and how they work, my question is if someone asks me how a particular recursive function works then I would be able to explain him without confusing myself).

Comment: In the `_remove` method, you're not returning anything in the last else branch, which might be why it's necessary.

Comment: No sadly that's not the case because if I move return node inside last else then the BST looses its nodes.